# Addin median line to my seaborn multi columns plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Can you please help me adding the median to each of the seaborn plots ? We have here one plot per specialty, and this is allowed by the following line of code:

`sns.displot(data=all_df, x="exp", hue="sexe", col='specialite', kind="kde")`, which gives:

[image]

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the medians manually, e.g. using `.map_dataframe()`. Here is some example code using the penguins dataset:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

def plot_medians(data, color):
    for hue, color in zip(hue_order, palette):
        plt.axvline(data[data['sex'] == hue][x_colummn].median(), color=color, ls=':')

penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins').dropna()
hue_order = penguins['sex'].unique()
palette = ['dodgerblue', 'crimson']
x_colummn = "bill_length_mm"
g = sns.displot(data=penguins, x=x_colummn,
                hue="sex", hue_order=hue_order, palette=palette,
                col="species", kind="kde")
g.map_dataframe(plot_medians)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.displot with medians]

Comment: Great ! This answers the question. Thank you